# OrientDB group by

Tags: orientdb

I developing a traffic counter and I want to get IP and repeat count, but how ?

Something like : 
`select ip, count(ip) from Redirect`

Return : 

`null total ip count`

Redirect is a bean which have 2 fields : ip, date

Answer (score 2):

OrientDB doesn't support the GROUP BY yet (look at [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/orient/issues/detail?id=577&q=group%20by)). So you can do it by:

1. using an index against the ip field and then lookup into the index to retrieve all the entries "grouped"
2. Group them by your self by creating a RedirectGroup with the "ip" field and a LINKSET to Redirect records. In this way just query the RedirectGroup and count the links (it's a collection, so do .size())

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
select ip, count(ip) 
from Redirect
GROUP BY IP
```

Comment: Query fails, work : select ip, count(ip) GROUP BY IP  from Redirect but with same result : null, total ip count

Answer (score 1):

According to OrientDB SQL documentation, `GROUP BY` is nowadays supported. It should behave like `GROUP BY` in SQL. I'm using version `orientdb-enterprise-2.0.3` and it really works without problems.

Comment: well, dropped  orientdb long time ago, now working with mongodb